# Avoiding double taxation on US income in Canada with tuition credits

Tags: united-states, canada, income-tax

I am a Canadian with some foreign income from US, for which I have paid taxes in the US. So I would be eligible for foreign tax credit in Canada. However, Canadian tax system uses my tuition tax credits instead of foreign tax credit. I was wondering how I can carry forward my tuition tax credits and use my foreign tax credits. Or any other workaround to avoid double taxation. Thanks.

Comment: Good question. It seems that tuition credits from Schedule 11 get used up before foreign tax credit (T2209 and T2036). Foreign tax credit on business income can be carried forward, but not for non-business income. I'm curious if anyone has any tips for this as well.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that you must claim your tuition tax credits on Schedule 11.  You can override the claim amount to zero and then carry forward any unused amounts to future years.  You could then claim your Foreign tax credits to offset any tax payable.

If for some reason you are "forced" to claim the tuition credits first, the foreign tax credits are not lost.  They can be carried forward for you to use in the future.

Hope this helps.